# Filtering InfoPath data connection

Tags: infopath-data-connections

I have some queries on the InfoPath secondary data connections and I'm hoping that I do get some answers

I have an InfoPath form into which I'm getting some information from another list. As it's not design friendly to pull all the information when the form loads, I would require a mechanism or a trigger using which I would like to query the data connection and display the information.

In my InfoPath, I have a drop down column DCity with values DCity1, DCity2, DCity3 and 3 single line text columns. Now based on my city selection, I would like to query the data connection and pull the city specific information only.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new data connection that would query the List from where you are willing to get the data.

- Select your drop down and from the Home tab, Select Manage rules option.
- Create a new Action rule. Add any condition that you want to add, if not then leave is as it is, i.e is "None - rule runs when field changes.". There will be several options and here you need to select `Query for data`.
- Select your secondary data connection name from the drop down and you are done.

Please see the image below:

[image]

After the 'Query for data' step, Add a new action below it to set the value of the text fields by using `Set a field's value` option.
See the image below for the option to be selected:

[image]

To conclude it would be getting the data and setting it in the field just in a single Action Rule.